# fabric 8 in openshift origin

Tags: openshift-origin, fabric8, openshift-enterprise

Is there a way to install fabric8 in already installed openshift origin 3.1 server? I have my origin server running ,I did install using ansible one node one master.
If yes how?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See [here](http://fabric8.io/guide/getStarted/openshift.html#run-the-gofabric8-installer). Essentially, download the latest gofabric8 from [here](https://github.com/fabric8io/gofabric8/releases). Then run:

```
gofabric8 deploy -y
gofabric8 secrets -y
```

Comment: @Jimmy- thanks a lot for response, I tried installing fabric 8 using the method in your answer , but as my environment is only for test and I don't have any domain name available , can not access it from browser. To test I tried using vagrant fabric8 installer from here http://blog.eisele.net/2015/09/running-openshift-origin-on-windows.html.But It gets stuck at this point forever:

==> default: Downloading docker images...

any idea why?

Comment: I also tried halting vagrant and then setting up fabric8 console in vagrant machine , but not able to access it on http://fabric8.vagrant.f8/ , any thoughts would be very helpful?

Comment: If you don't have a DNS zone you can update to add the entries in then you should be able to just edit your machine's `/etc/hosts` file (or equivalent on Windows - possibly `c:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`) to add the hosts entries in, something like:

    `172.17.28.4 fabric8.vagrant.f8`

In production you'll want to of course have a valid DNS set up for your OpenShift router domain,

Comment: @Jimmy - yes that's already done by Vagrant . I have entry in hosts file. still cant access :(

Comment: Have you deployed the openshift router? See [here](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.0/install_config/install/deploy_router.html). This is all handled in the fabric8 vagrant box but is a separate step if you're doing it manually.

Comment: @Jimmy : yes it should work that way, but  Vagrant machine hangs forever if I try to pull any docker image for router creation. Yesterday I waited for about 2 hrs , but it didn't complete and my machine hanged very  badly :( is this is happening only with me or you have also faced this with fabric8-vagrant machine. thanks a lot for help

Comment: I know of a lot of people using it successfully. My guess is there's something in your environment that is causing it to fail. Can you manually pull images from docker hub on the VM?

Comment: @Jimmy could you please also tell me what is this 172.28.128.4 ?? looks to be some private ip but not sure, thankyou so much !

Comment: You said you're using the fabric8 vagrantfile which assigns the private IP 172.28.128.4 to the VM interface. This gives a static address you can reuse between recreating the vagrant box, which otherwise could change every time (annoying when you want to address it consistently).